# How to determine SSL cert expiration date from NSURLAuthenticationMethodServerTrust challenge

Tags: ios, ssl-certificate, nsurlconnection

Inside the delegate

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection willSendRequestForAuthenticationChallenge:(NSURLAuthenticationChallenge *)challenge
```

After getting Server Challenge, i am able to extract  X.509 Certificate using following code:

```
    SecTrustRef serverTrust = challenge.protectionSpace.serverTrust;
    SecCertificateRef certificate = SecTrustGetCertificateAtIndex(serverTrust, 0);
```

Now I Need to get the expire date from this SecCertificateRef.

And also want to check whether the certificate is having valid domain name.
I have gone through apple docs and googled for long time, some suggested to use SLL library to get these details. In project no Third party libraries are permitted. Is any way to get these details without third party libs?

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Security/Conceptual/CertKeyTrustProgGuide/iPhone_Tasks/iPhone_Tasks.html

Comment: go through this docs as well, Only Trust verification steps are there. Need to know how the end date can get from SecCertificateRef